# Serialization error with custom getter

Tags: symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I have an entity with two manyToOne that a want to wrap during serialization.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Fleet;

use AppBundle\Entity\Account\Site;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Equipment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Account\Site")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $siteOwner;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Account\Contact")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $contactOwner;
}
```

Serialized into

```
{
    "owner": {
        "site": {...},
        "contact": {...}
    }
}
```

So I made a simple getter.

```
/**
 * @Groups({"read"})
 */
public function getOwner()
{
    return [
        'site' => $this->siteOwner,
        'contact' => $this->contactOwner,
    ];
}
```

`Site` and `Contact` entities are also ApiResource with working endpoints. But I get an error during serialization : `No resource class found for object of type "AppBundle\Entity\Account\Site".`

Any idea ?

**Update**

I was able to reproduce the same problem with the api-platform demo. I have forked the base demo, and [added a custom getter on the review entity](https://github.com/erichard/demo/commit/04e82fcef96968256bebf097eaf45a58fb2cdcc9).

Got the same `No resource class found for object of type AppBundle\Entity\Book`

Comment: Error says that system is not aware how to serialise AppBundle\Entity\Account\Site.
Could you update your question with few code samples: annotations and "use" section for your entity and for class "AppBundle\Entity\Account\Site" ?

Comment: In fact I think this a bug in api-platform, i've submitted an issue in the github.

Comment: No, `$this->siteOwner` is an object from class `Site` - if you don't have any serializing option for `Site` your Getter will fail as it cannot serialize `Site`. That's exactly what @MaksymMoskvychev tried to explain.